# Can't remove borders from tables in Word export

Tags: html, asp.net, ms-word, html-table

I'm having an issue when I export my html page to Word, I can't get rid of the borders on a table element.

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td class="title">Analyst</td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lblAnalyst" runat="server" CssClass="data" />
        </td>
        <td class="title">Borrower</td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lblBorrower" runat="server" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I set the content type to Word

```
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-word";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", String.Concat("attachment;filename=", fileName));
```

No matter what I do, I still get the borders around the entire table and around each cell.

[image: Link to picture]

I've tried setting the borders attribute on the table to 0, using inline styles and including a style in a  section but nothing works.  I've even tried all 3 of these together.

Any ideas?  This is destined for Word 2003.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using WordML rather than plain old HTML? Word is incredibly weird about how it imports HTML.

My suggestion would be to export a table *from* Word in HTML, and mimic that HTML precisely. Chances are, it will involve some funky naming for stylesheet classes and a small army of Word-specific CSS directives.

Comment: This worked perfectly.  Great idea.  

It turns out that Word was just showing the table outline.  Once printed, the lines are gone.  Thank you. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Got a workaround after searchin a lot. :D

Change the **table** as

<table **border="1" style="border: 1px white solid"** cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" >

then on **each td** provide inline style(or give a class) and add the following style

**border: 1px white solid**

Thats all. You are done :)

/* John JB */

jcb871@gmail.com