# Creating tables without frames

Tags: html

I want to draw a table like this

[image]
however I couldn't find code for using (creating flatlines)

Which tag can I use=?

Comment: Read [http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't remove borders from tables in Word export](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869849/cant-remove-borders-from-tables-in-word-export)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse; /* Merge borders of neighbouring cells */
  border: 2px solid black;
}
tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #ddd;  /* Alternate background colors on rows */
}
td, th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>URUN KODU</th>
      <td>Encoder</td>
      <td>PWM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr> <!-- this is empty row that spans whole table and acts as "double line" -->
      <td colspan="3"> <!-- Update "colspan" attribute to number of columns -->
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>M91-2-T1</th>
      <td>2</td>
      <td rowspan="2"> <!-- that's the cell that spans two rows -->
        2 (0,5 KHz)
      </td>
    <tr>
      <th>M91-2-T38</th>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```